# iOS: copy image from gallery to documents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gallery

Is there a way to copy an image from iOS gallery to app`s documents folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't post the code coz I dint remember it.
First get UIImage from the gallery then convert
that Image into NSData and then write that NSData
to a file in your document directory.